# Selection statement using alias inside expression

Tags: sql-server, pervasive-sql

Is there a way to use an expression inside another expression? I want to calculate profit base on Revenue (Extension) - Cost of Goods (LMOZ)

Looking for something like this: SUM("Extension") - SUM("LMOZ")  AS Profit.

Sample Query:

```
Select distinct Top 10 rtrim(customer) as SaleCust,Sum(Extension) As Extension,
SUM(COST_Material) + SUM(Cost_Labor) + SUM(Cost_Outside) + SUM(Cost_Overhead) + SUM(Cost_Other) AS LMOZ 
From V_Order_Hist_Line 
Where Year(Date_Invoice) = 2018 AND Salesperson = 'DJW' AND PRODUCT_LINE LIKE 'R_' 
Group By rtrim(customer)
ORDER BY Extension desc
```

Comment: Attempted both suggestions, no dice. A sub-query is the right direction however, it would appear pervasive sub-query syntax is different from sql-server.

The following types of subqueries are supported:
    - comparison
    - quantified
    - in
    - exists
    - correlated
    - expression
reference: https://communities.actian.com/s/question/0D53300003xeoDvCAI/sql-query-with-subquery-in-from-clause

Any suggestion on how to get the syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a subquery to get column aliases in scope or repeat it all once again.

Subquery template:

```
SELECT *, Extension - LMOZ AS Profit
FROM ( ... your query ... ) alias
```

Incorporated in your query:

```
SELECT *, Extension - LMOZ AS Profit
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
    rtrim(customer) AS SaleCust,
    SUM(Extension) AS Extension,
    SUM(COST_Material) + SUM(Cost_Labor) + SUM(Cost_Outside) + SUM(Cost_Overhead) + SUM(Cost_Other) AS LMOZ 
  FROM V_Order_Hist_Line 
  WHERE Year(Date_Invoice) = 2018 AND Salesperson = 'DJW' AND PRODUCT_LINE LIKE 'R_' 
  GROUP BY rtrim(customer)
  ORDER BY Extension DESC
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query but order by won't work inside sub query. You can do something like as follows.

```
SELECT distinct Top 10 SaleCust, (Extension -  LMOZ) AS Calc, OrdExtension
FROM (
Select  rtrim(customer) as SaleCust,Sum(Extension) As Extension,
SUM(COST_Material) + SUM(Cost_Labor) + SUM(Cost_Outside) + SUM(Cost_Overhead) + SUM(Cost_Other) AS LMOZ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Extension DESC) AS OrdExtension
From V_Order_Hist_Line 
Where Year(Date_Invoice) = 2018 AND Salesperson = 'DJW' AND PRODUCT_LINE LIKE 'R_' 
Group By rtrim(customer)
)
ORDER BY OrdExtension desc
```